# Generate parameterized ppt reports using officer

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, purrr, officer

Using code below, I'm able to generate a ppt report for subset of `mtcars` dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
library(officer)
library(officedown)
library(glue)

small <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(carb %in% c(1, 2))

p1 <- ggplot(mpg, wt, data = small, colour = cyl)
p2 <- ggplot(mpg, data = small) + ggtitle("small")
p <- p1 | p2

template_pptx <- read_pptx()
report <- add_slide(template_pptx, layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>%
  ph_with(value=p, location = ph_location_label(ph_label = "Content Placeholder 2"))
print(report, target=glue('report for small car.pptx'))
```

Now let's say we need to reproduce the report generating process for the following datasets as well:

```
middle <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(carb %in% c(3, 4))

large <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(carb %in% c(6, 8))
```

My ideas is to convert multiple ggplots part to a function and save in a script `plot.R`, then I will write pseudocode script named `main.R` to run the whole process and generate 3 reports for small, middle, large datasets respectively:

```
# main.R
for i in c(small, middle, large){
  source('plot.R')
  # maybe need to import and run plot function() from plot.R
  # save figure to ppt
  template_pptx <- read_pptx("./ppt_template.pptx")
  report <- add_slide(template_pptx, layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>%
  ph_with(value=p, location = ph_location_label(ph_label = "Content Placeholder 2"))
  print(report, target=glue('report for {i} car.pptx'))
}
```

The problem I met is I don't know how to convert plotting code to a function and pass params (maybe save a `config.yaml` file in case we have many params?) to the predefined function, and finally generate a parameterized report?

Many thanks for your comments and help at advance.

**References:**

[R: multiple ggplot2 plot using d*ply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869040/r-multiple-ggplot2-plot-using-dply)

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html

[R - How to generate parameterized reports via nested tibbles + pwalk(rmarkdown::render)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53529644/r-how-to-generate-parameterized-reports-via-nested-tibbles-pwalkrmarkdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your plotting code in a function which e.g. takes two arguments, a dataframe (x) and a title.

Similarly put the code to prepare the pptx inside a function, which e.g. takes two arguments, a dataframe (x) and a title or filename or ...

In my code below I have put your three datasets in a list and then make use of `purrr::iwalk` to loop over this list to make a pptx report for each dataset. Using `purrr::iwalk` the name of the dataset is passed as the second argument to the reporting function.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(officer)
library(glue)

plot_fun <- function(x, title) {
  p1 <- ggplot(data = x, aes(mpg, wt, colour = cyl))
  p2 <- ggplot(data = x, aes(mpg)) + ggtitle(title)
  p1 | p2
}

pptx_fun <- function(x, y) {
  p <- plot_fun(x, title = y)
  template_pptx <- read_pptx()
  report <- add_slide(template_pptx, layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>%
    ph_with(value = p, location = ph_location_label(ph_label = "Content Placeholder 2"))
  print(report, target=glue('report for {y} car.pptx'))
}

data_list <- lapply(list(small = 1:2, medium = 3:4, large = 5:6), function(x) filter(mtcars, carb %in% x))

purrr::iwalk(data_list, pptx_fun)
```

Comment: Another master in R sharing this beautiful and concise solution, thanks for your help.

Comment: Btw, out of topic, do you know what does `|>` represent in R? I didn't find it.

Comment: That's the new native pipe operator introduced with R 4.0.0. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/what-are-the-differences-between-rs-new-native-pipe-and-the-magrittr-pipe for a discussion compared to the `magrittr` pipe `%>%`

Comment: Ok, I understand. :)